# Fixed width TextView next to variable width TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to create a layout with two `TextViews` next to each other. The first `TextView` has a variable length and is single-lined. The second `TextView` contains a fixed label and should **not** be ellipsized.
The second label has to be right next to the first one.
Here are two examples of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]
[image]

This is what I've achieved so far:

[image]

With this layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/my_bg"
            android:padding="16dp"
tools:layout_height="60dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/tv_street"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_updated"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    tools:text="This label is short"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@id/tv_updated"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="@string/updated"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The remaining problem is that the container gets a width that matches its parent while it should be `wrap_content`.

Are there any other ways to fix this?

Comment: is right one text you want to fixed right or it will be always adjust with first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you better use linearlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:padding="16dp"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              tools:layout_height="60dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_street"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        tools:text="This label is short"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/tv_updated"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="UPDATED"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

edited:
here the prove

[image: tested]

Comment: This will cause the UPDATED textview to get pushed off the screen

Comment: do you try it? i test and its not pushed because layout_weight

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. Might need a little tweaking but a couple of hidden views may achieve what you're looking for.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:layout_height="60dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/tv_street"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        tools:text="This label is short" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/hidden_street"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/hidden_updated"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        tools:text="This label is short"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_updated"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_street"
        android:text="updated"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hidden_updated"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="updated"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

check below code it will help you

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
    >


        <TextView
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/tv_street"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_updated"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            tools:text="This  is fdfdfffddfdfdfffdfdfdfdffshort"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/tv_updated"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Updated"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

as per your requirement LinearLayout is better option if not works let me know

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted here are when no other elements are present in layout.

I present a solution to be used inside RelativeLayout where you may have fixed end views or other views. (use case: product item in shopping list view)

Main idea is to wrap textViews inside a LinearLayout and let linear layout vary in size in correspondence to its children. TextViews remain side by side always. Assign variable TextView width as 0dp and weightage as 1 (one). Then assign fixed TextView width to wrap_content.

Making textView width 0dp with weight = 1 causes it to be stretchable and occupy all available remaining space.

Now, LinearLayout would grow in either direction due to variable text, any may overlap with other views.

However, if we try to alignEndOf and alignStartOf LinearLayout to fix boundary, framework will fix size of LinearLayout stretching between endpoints. This will cause variable textView to cover all remaining available space even though content text is not large enough.

This led, fixed textView to be placed near to right endpoint with empty space between variable text of smaller content length and itself.

Hence, the proposed solution. Introduce another layout to fix boundary and let inner linear layout to grow or collapse freely within outer layout limits.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/leftView"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/rightView"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/card_name"
                style="@style/textStyleCardName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Platinum Card" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/card_number"
                style="@style/textStyleCardNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="none"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="**** 3308" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```